# Sybase sp_sendmsg/syb_sendmsg performance

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I find that Sybase is only able to send 2 or 3 UDPs per second using sp_sendmsg (or the function it calls, syb_sendmsg.)

If I run a little perl script on the same host, I can send 1000s per second, as I might expect.

So Sybase is doing something funny when sending udps.

Has anyone tried this?

Anyone know what limits this?

Comment: What Sybase product are you running?

Answer (score 0):

It may be a mis-match between the Sybase ASE setting for default packet size, and the pysical packet size for the OS.

From Jeff Garbus' *Administrators Guide to Sybase 15*:

> When you are sending large amounts of data across the network frequently, you can get a significant performance benefit by matching up the ASE *default network packet size* ... with the physical network packet size.

[The excerpt here talks about tuning the network settings](http://books.google.com/books?id=Zv9XP8HIsFIC&lpg=PA252&ots=InKwn_YWO1&dq=syb_sendmsg%20performance&pg=PA252#v=onepage&q=syb_sendmsg%20performance&f=false).

Comment: so you reckon maybe ase buffers up the udps if it can?  But that seems strange - if so, it spoils the performance of syb_sendmsg, which doesn't return for 200/300 ms.  I'll have a look though - it's a theory; also we have a Sybase case and I'll see if they'll comment.  Thanks very much for answering.